# Django: How to prevent duplicates when using "Signals" with "dispatch_uid"?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

Hello i am testing Django User/ AUTH nesting with other models.

i made a simple model for my User called `MyProfil`. Everytime a new `User` is registered a new `MyProfil` object will created automatically and linked to the specific `User`.

> models.py

```
#-- create a MyProfil.object for new user 
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_myprofil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
            MyProfil.objects.create(owner=instance)



class MyProfil(models.Model):
    # --- head
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    oblink = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # --- body
    aboutme = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    city = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

---

> **Question**

The Django Doc mentioned to use`dispatch_uid` to prevent that maybe duplicates will send. Unfortunately i don´t really understand how to apply `dispatch_uid` so ended up with this approach for receiver.

> models.py

```
    <...>
from django.core.signals import request_finished



#-- create a MyProfil.object for new user 
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
def create_myprofil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
            MyProfil.objects.create(owner=instance)

request_finished.connect(create_myprofil, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")

<...>
```

So my question is if this the right way to apply `dispatch_uid` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `dispatch_uid` to make sure that the same event handler is never attached more than once for the same model/event.

For instance consider this code:

```
request_finished.connect(my_callback)
request_finished.connect(my_callback)
```

When the `request_finished` event is fired, the function `my_callback` will be called twice since it was registered two times. This can be avoided by passing `dispatch_uid` when the callback is connected.

```
request_finished.connect(my_callback, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
request_finished.connect(my_callback, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still a little bit confused regarding the semantic in the django docs. So "event handlers" are the Signals (`post_save` etc.) and "signal handlers" are my function like in my example `create_myprofil`? So the sender wraps a identifier around a signal and `request_finished.connect(dispatch_uid=)` wraps the identifier around my `signal handler`(`def create_myprofil`)? So if my `signal handler` has not the same identifier nothing happens?